# Sending Command Line Parameters to Chrome When Selenium Node Starts

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a Selenium Hub with 2 nodes on Windows machines which are started through batch scripts.

When starting the Chrome browser on these nodes with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -role -node -hub http...
```

I'd like to have the opportunity to provide command line parameter to the Chrome instance when it is started. Specifically I want to make use of the

```
--user-agent=[user agent]
```

parameter to set the http user agent that Chrome sends to the web server.

Does anyone of you have an idea about how to go about this?

If tried stuff like

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=[path to chromedriver] --user-agent=[user agent]
```

but when I do that the chromedriver executable cannout be found by the system.

Cool would be to have something like

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.browser="user-agent=[user agent]"
```

but I did not find anything helpful.

It would be very nice if somebody could help me out here ...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for exactly.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");
```

You need to pass this options to your chrome capability.

List of all command line switches of chrome are provided below.

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would actually prefer to have a non-language dependent solution (yours only works in Java), though, since I'm currently required to use the Behat (cf. [link](http://behat.org) ) framework - that is, I'm working in PHP.

Comment: You could do the samething in any other selenium supported language.

Comment: Just use the appropriate language syntax.